# SQLite and hierarchy in one request, how to do so?

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion, hierarchy

**Facts**

I have a pretty simple table:

```
ID, name, PARENT_ID
```

I would like to retrieve the hierarchy from down to top in one query using SQLite.

**Question : How can I do that ?**

Is there any request that will let me do that in One request?

I´ve read about the 'Modified Preorder Tree Traversal', it is straight forward to get the hierarchy from top to down, but how can I get it from down to top (in one query)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do a closure query in SQLite.